# How do I iterate through an object which contain children objects with the same type as the object?

Tags: java, xml, arrays, iteration, object-model

Allright, I have reached the mindscrew of the century and sat a few hours cogitating this one. I will quickly add an example here:

```
public class AdUnitSizes {

protected String environmentType;
@XmlElement(name = "size")
protected List<Size> sizes;
protected List<Companions> companions;
```

Now basically, if I were to structure this as an XML file, it would hypothetically represent something like this (Note, Companions is of type AdUnitSize[])

```
    <adUnitSizes>
    <size>
        <width>800</width>
        <height>600</height>
        <isAspectRatio>true</isAspectRatio>
    </size>
    <environmentType>BROWSER</environmentType>
    <companions>  <!--adunitsize[]-->
        <size>
            <width>800</width>
            <height>600</height>
            <isAspectRatio>true</isAspectRatio>
        </size>
        <environmentType>BROWSER</environmentType>
        <companions>
            <size>
                <width>800</width>
                <height>600</height>
                <isAspectRatio>true</isAspectRatio>
            </size>
            <environmentType>BROWSER</environmentType>
            <companions>...</companions>    
        </companions>               
    </companions>
</adUnitSizes>
```

Now, As I am trying to point out, AdUnitSizes contains 3 fields. Sizes, EnvironmentTypes and Companions. What I am trying to do in java now, using the object wrapper I have created (1st example) is to Iterate through each and every child Companions Object, And their children Companions Objects till the iteration can go no further (its unlikely in our system that Companions will go more than 3 levels deep, but I need to cater for this anyway)

This is what I have tried:

```
    AdUnitSize[] adUnitSizeArray = adUnit.getAdUnitSizes();
    if(adUnitSizeArray != null){
        List<AdUnitSizes> adUnitSizesList = adUnitWrapper.getAdUnitSizes();
        for(int i = 0; i < adUnitSizeArray.length; i++){
            AdUnitSizes adUnitSizes = new AdUnitSizes();

            aem.adservices.google.dfp6.om.Size size = new aem.adservices.google.dfp6.om.Size(); //Name clash with Google Size Class
            size.setHeight(adUnitSizeArray[i].getSize().getHeight());
            size.setWidth(adUnitSizeArray[i].getSize().getWidth());
            size.setIsAspectRatio(adUnitSizeArray[i].getSize().getIsAspectRatio());
            adUnitSizes.getSizes().add(size);

            adUnitSizes.setEnvironmentType(adUnitSizeArray[i].getEnvironmentType().getValue());

            List<Companions> companionsList = adUnitSizes.getCompanions();
            //Need to iterate through all of adUnitSizeArray's Companions, and its companions children and so forth
        }
    }
```

Any ideas? Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: have you tried `for(Companions companions: companionsList) { ... }`

Comment: Isn't this a trivial exercise in recursion?

Comment: See, this is the problem, Companions, in turn , also contains Companions.

so that Cannot work. `for(Companions companions: companionsList) { //Contains Sizes, Environment Types, Companions ( 0 or more) } How would I iterate through those Child companions?

Comment: I guess you can say it is recursive, but I need to parse all these google dfp objects (received from an XML Response in Boomi) back to the wrapper Object, and I am mindscrewed how to get a recursive object back into its List<Companions> wrapper object

Comment: BTW, check XStream, it helps a lot with parsing and creating xml, maybe that helps you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure awhat you're doing with the companyList, but as Dave said, is a trivial exercise of recursion, so you can do:

```
    //(...)
    List<Companions> companionsList = adUnitSizes.getCompanions();
    iterateOverCompanions(companionsList);
}

private void iterateOverCompanions(List<Companions> companionsList) {
    for(Companions companion : companionsList) {
        //Do stuff with companion
        List<Companions> anotherCompanionList = companion.getCompanionsList();
        if (anotherCompanionList  != null && anotherCompanionList.size()>0) {
            iterateOverCompanions(anotherCompanionList);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you need to pass something to populate, you can just pass them as a parameter like:

```
iterateOverCompanions(List<Companions> companionsList, Size size, AnotherStuff stuff)
```

or set it as a member variable, if this is ok.

Comment: worth a try, will give it a shot, Reminds me of something very hazily what I used to do in C# and got crapped out over years ago

Comment: Check my edit and see if it helps you with the comment you made

Comment: Companions already contains all the fields it needs to populate, along with its children. Your example works, thanks.